# React Router V4 is updating URL, but not refreshing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I create simple app and i try use in it react-router but i have problem.
When user click register or login the page should render necessary form but now to page change user must refresh page and then page change component i dont know why.

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

App class:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Navbar class:

```
 class  Navbar extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return (
        <Nav bsStyle="tabs"> 
            <LinkContainer to="/login" >
                <NavItem >
                        LogIn
                </NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/Register" >
                <NavItem >
                    Register
                </NavItem>  
            </LinkContainer>
            <Router>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/Register" component={Register}  />
                        <Route path="/Login" component={Login}  />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Router>
        </Nav> 
    ) 
}}
```

Comment: You `BrowserRouter` should be a top level component. And why do you 2 of them in place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to have your `BrowserRouter` as a top level component. The `nav` is the place which triggers what component has to be rendered.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
           <Navbar/>

           <Router>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/Register" component={Register}  />
                        <Route path="/Login" component={Login}  />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Nav.js**

```
class  Navbar extends React.Component {
 render(){
    return (
        <Nav bsStyle="tabs"> 
            <LinkContainer to="/login" >
                <NavItem >
                        LogIn
                </NavItem>
            </LinkContainer>
            <LinkContainer to="/Register" >
                <NavItem >
                    Register
                </NavItem>  
            </LinkContainer>
        </Nav> 
    ) 
}}
```

Comment: @TomKarnaski Glad it worked out for you. If this solved the problem, accept the one that solved your issue so that it would help others looking fro answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have your Routing inside the `Navbar` component, that won't work.

Change your index.js to look like this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Register" component={Register}  />
          <Route path="/Login" component={Login}  />
          <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

That should work, let me know if any issues.  Also delete the `BrowserRouter` elements and children from Navbar

Answer (score 0):

use BrowserRouter inside Router

```
<Router>
   <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
...
      </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
</Router>
```

Comment: Please add a description that explains why is your solution solves his problem or what has he done wrong